# NextJS: How to send data from one page to another page's getInitialProps function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm trying to send data from Page B (login) to Page A's (index) `getInitialProps` as I need a key for Page A's getInitProps to actually get the props...

I'm currently trying to do it by sending a POST request to a custom express route and use that route to render the Page server side so getInitialProps will run. But the problem is that the browser won't render the page even though it gets built server side.

POST Request From Login Page (happens Client Side):

```
const headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
await fetch(`${getRootUrl()}/loadKey`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({key}), headers})
```

Express Route:

```
server.post('/loadKey', (req, res) => {
    // const {key} = req.body
    // console.log(key)
    next({dev}).render('/') //index page
})
```

The key gets logged fine and in the terminal, nextjs is saying that the index page is getting built,and getInitialProps gets ran, but nothing happens on the browser. No redirect.

I've tried using `express.redirect`, `express.render`, and I've tried to force a client-side redirect, but for the former two, the same thing happens when I use next.render; the page gets built, getInitialProps runs, but no redirect happens on the browser. And when I force a redirect using Link or Router, then Index's getInitialProps won't get the key passed in from the POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
server.post('/loadKey', (req, res) => {
    const {key} = req.body
    // Do whatever you need to do
    const actualPage = '/'
    const queryParams = { key }
    next({dev}).render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```

Now you should have access to `key` in index page by props.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will only work for server-side rendered pages (since you need to use `req`), not for client-side. Even if you get it work once, your logic might break when you try navigating to this route, or you might end up with part of your app being SPA and then some refreshes when visiting this page.

From nextjs documentation:

> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will execute on the server only. getInitialProps will only be executed on the client when navigating to a different route via the Link component or using the routing APIs.

Some possible solutions that I've used in the past:

- Implement your page B as a component, and call it from page A if certain criteria it's met. Page B won't have getInitialProps but page A does, and it seems like you need to know something from page A getInitialProps in order to correctly render page B, so why not use a single page instead? The user won't know the difference.
- Use Redux or the likes. You can store the value of your prop in the store, which it's available globally, even to getInitialProps. But beware! Save your prop to the store *before* trying to access it on page B. A page's getInitialProps runs before the HoC's.

Comment: Sorry if I was a little confusing. But I need something from Page B for Page A to render with initial data. But you're right. The logic I would implement would break on client-side routing. My setup before I started on this path was as you said it, Page B was a component of Page A, but then Page A wouldn't get the initial data it needed from Page B Component because it would have already ran it's getInitialprops function. And I think I will end up going the Redux approach, but like I said-little backwards. Need to access the prop on the store in Page A but Page B would be putting it there.

Comment: I don't think that's possible... If Page A needs it from Page B, but page A runs first and then B... hmmm, it sounds like you'd need to _really_ hack your way around it. Better to use Redux, it probably will save you a lot of headaches and make your code cleaner :)

Comment: Hahhaha you're right on the money. I was trying to hack my way around it by using Page B to send the data to the server which would re-server render page A with the data. I ended up going with redux like you said and it's muchhhh better, so thank you!

Comment: Welcome @ohryan! If you think my answer it's the correct one, please mark it as so.

Comment: While your answer helped me more in my situation, it wasn't an answer to the question proposed =( I want to, but if people come to this post looking for the answer of the title question, this answer may not suit them whereas MoHo's answer accomplished exactly what I thought I needed when I post the question. Let me know if you disagree.